# Oracle SQL sorting issue

Tags: c#, sql

We have status column in a table in database. It has 30 distinct values. I want to sort it on the basis of Status Column keeping in mind that Closed defects should come at the end. Distinct values may change.

Comment: Please provide relevant Table structure and data and what you tried for the same https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score 1):

Your question is *vague* one, however, it seems you are looking for something like this:

```
  select ...
    from MyTable
order by case -- Closed should be in the end
           when Status = 10 then -- Put the right constant for Closed here
             1 
           else 
             0
         end,
         Status -- if Status is not "Closed", order by Status
```